# Which + Noun : is a noun following after which?

Tags: nouns, that

Recently I have been learning SAT sentence correction, there is one sentence I don't quite understand. Here ...

Begining in 1285, various commissions were set up in London to address the problem of coal smoke, which complainants said had "infected and corrupted" the air.

My question is - which complainants - I feel like it should have "that complainants" instead of "which + complainants". Is "which" normally used like "that"?

Comment: From the fact that the phrase "the problem of coal smoke" is used, you should conclude that somebody has complained enough about coal smoke to get commissions set up. Those people were _the complainants_, spoken of in much the same way as _the voters_ -- faceless members of some identifiable group.

Comment: No; we can't use "that" in a non-restrictive relative clause, thus only "which" is possible.

Answer (score 1):

"which complainants said had "infected and corrupted" the air" is a nonrestrictive clause that modifies "the problem of coal smoke". "Which" is appropriate for a nonrestrictive clause: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/that_vs_which.html . Using "that" would imply that it's a restrictive clause, which in turn implies that there are several problems of coal smoke, and you are specifying that you are talking about the one that people have complained about.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Now I completely understand.

Comment: Yes, but non-restrictive relative clauses are supplements, not modifiers. They have a semantic 'anchor' that they refer to, which happens to be the same as the antecedent. In this case the anchor is "coal smoke".